# JavaMail : Concurrent read-only processing of emails and EXPUNGE issues

Tags: java, multithreading, exchange-server, jakarta-mail, imap

I’m currently working on a solution based on JavaMail, which retrieves emails from a specific folder (Inbox), performs some processing, moves them to another folder (Processed) and finally deletes them from the first folder.

Due to certain performance requirements I've used a dispatcher/processor approach, where one thread (dispatcher) retrieves a set of UIDs and spawns a number of separate threads (workers) that retrieve the emails for the UIDs read by the dispatcher. After the mails have been processed the dispatcher thread copies them to a Processed folder and deletes them from the Inbox folder. So basically the idea is that the reading is done in parallel.
Each thread uses a separate connection (separate store) to the mail server. Currently the folders are opened prior to a specific operation/set of operations (e.g. open -> copy and delete -> close etc.) and closed after the operation is completed.

The initial tests were successful, but recently I've been having some problems with the solution, so I wanted to kind of “validate” the approach and see if other people have used something similar.

The problem I referred to above is with the EXPUNGE – basically from time to time (no pattern from what I can see) the EXPUNGE command simply fails and I’m not able to delete certain messages.

A12 STORE 1:7 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
* 1 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen \Deleted))
* 2 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen \Deleted))
* 3 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen \Deleted))
* 4 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen \Deleted))
* 5 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen \Deleted))
* 6 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen \Deleted))
* 7 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen \Deleted))
A12 OK STORE completed.
...
A15 SELECT INBOX
* 7 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 55702] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 10557] The next unique identifier value
A15 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
A16 EXPUNGE
* 0 EXISTS
A16 NO EXPUNGE failed.

Tried also to expunge only specific messages with the UID EXPUNGE command – same problem.

A14 UID EXPUNGE 10557
* 6 EXISTS
A14 NO EXPUNGE failed.

The interesting thing is that sometimes the problem disappears by it self - for example in one case after a couple of hours the EXPUNGE worked just fine.

If it makes any difference the mail server is MS Exchange.

To summarize - I'd really appreciate if somebody can share his opinion regarding:
1. Concurrent retrieval of emails from a mailbox
2. What might be going wrong with the EXPUNGE

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no experience with MS Exchange. But I have seen that some servers don't like to expunge while there are other clients accessing the same mailbox (expunging during concurrent access is a bit tricky). You might want to test whether that is the problem.

Or you might just sidestep the issue by shifting your lock/test to `\deleted`. Call `store +flags.silent \deleted` once you've processed a message, and if you see a message with the `\deleted` flag, don't process that. Then send `expunge` from time to time and ignore its result (if one fails, the next one will likely work).

Comment: Or, instead of calling expunge explicitly, call close(true) occasionally.  It does look like an Exchange bug/problem, however.  What you're doing sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Today the expunge for the problematic emails worked just fine, as if something got "reset" after specific period of time. Same thing happened with all other emails for which the EXPUNGE did not work - i.e. after some time it eventually goes through. As for calling close(true) - I tried that and did not get an error, but it seems that the EXPUNGE command is not sent at all in this case (at least I don't see it in the debug logs and the messages are also not deleted on the server).

Comment: I also have some doubts that the Exchange might be to blame and next week I'll have a chat with an Exchange expert in the organization that I work so we'll see. Once I have more news I'll post an update.

Comment: The suggestion with using the delete flag and calling expunge until it succeeds sounds like a reasonable workaround, however do you know if it is possible for the delete flag to get reset somehow (e.g. by another client or after specific period of time has passed etc.) after I've set it - i.e. how reliable would that approach be?

Comment: I would be astonished if \delete were cleared. Strictly speaking it could happen, but if it were to happen, then it would surely be discussed on the imap mailing list, and that hasn't happened. You can check it, though: When you open the mailbox you'll get a line containing the word permamentflags. If that contains either \\* or \deleted, then the server is promising that \deleted is stored permanently.

Comment: The problem is still not resolved (after lots of discussions, tests etc.), so I went with the workaround suggested by Amt.